# zip function with 3 parameter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I want to transpose multiple columns in Spark SQL table
I found this solution for only two columns, I want to know how to work with zip function with three column `varA, varB and varC.`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, explode}

val zip = udf((xs: Seq[Long], ys: Seq[Long]) => xs.zip(ys))

df.withColumn("vars", explode(zip($"varA", $"varB"))).select(
   $"userId", $"someString",
   $"vars._1".alias("varA"), $"vars._2".alias("varB")).show
```

this is my dataframe schema :

```
`root
 |-- owningcustomerid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_stoptime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- balancename: string (nullable = false)
 |-- chargedvalue: string (nullable = false)
 |-- newbalance: string (nullable = false)
`
```

i tried this code :

```
    val zip = udf((xs: Seq[String], ys: Seq[String], zs: Seq[String]) => (xs, ys, zs).zipped.toSeq)

df.printSchema

val df4=df.withColumn("vars", explode(zip($"balancename", $"chargedvalue",$"newbalance"))).select(
   $"owningcustomerid", $"event_stoptime",
   $"vars._1".alias("balancename"), $"vars._2".alias("chargedvalue"),$"vars._2".alias("newbalance"))
```

i got this error :

```
cannot resolve 'UDF(balancename, chargedvalue, newbalance)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array<string> type, however, '`balancename`' is of string type. argument 2 requires array<string> type, however, '`chargedvalue`' is of string type. argument 3 requires array<string> type, however, '`newbalance`' is of string type.;;
```

'Project [owningcustomerid#1085, event_stoptime#1086, balancename#1159, chargedvalue#1160, newbalance#1161, explode(UDF(balancename#1159, chargedvalue#1160, newbalance#1161)) AS vars#1167]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala in general you can use `Tuple3.zipped`

```
val zip = udf((xs: Seq[Long], ys: Seq[Long], zs: Seq[Long]) => 
  (xs, ys, zs).zipped.toSeq)

zip($"varA", $"varB", $"varC")
```

Specifically in Spark SQL (>= 2.4) you can use `arrays_zip` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.arrays_zip

arrays_zip($"varA", $"varB", $"varC")
```

However you have to note that your data doesn't contain `array<string>` but plain `strings` - hence Spark `arrays_zip` or explode are not allowed and you should parse your data first.

Comment: The schema shows clearly that you don't have array columns - in such case zipping is not meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

```
val zip = udf((a: Seq[String], b: Seq[String], c: Seq[String], d: Seq[String]) => {a.indices.map(i=> (a(i), b(i), c(i), d(i)))})
```